# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

i 'm working with web app. i have found error during compile time. this error occurs from this code:

```
public static void SendRegistrationEmail(string name, string ref_no, string email)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = GetSmtpClient();
        string fromEmailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EASYTRACK_FromEmailAddress"];
        string appPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EASYTRACK_PathToApplication"];
        string subject = "EASYTRACK | User Registration";
        string body = "<html><body>Thank you " + name + " !" +
                    " for registering your details with Easy Track.<br/><br/>" +
                    "Please click the following link to activate your account" +
                    "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("Register.aspx", appPath + "My_Account.aspx?Ref=" + ref_no) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a><br/><br/>" +
                    "Thanks & Regards From Easy Track Team<br/></br></br><b>Note:</b>Your Account is activated after clicking this link.</body></html>";
        msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;
        client.Send(msg);
    }
```

here error occurs from Request.Url.AbsoluteUri here i can not get this Request how ever at Page_Load i can get. what was issue that???

Comment: Why is this method static?  Making it non-static should solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Page` class instance has the `Request` property so that you can easily work with it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Your code being static method, instead, doesn't have access to `Request` property, since static methods do not have access to instance members.

Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` instead `of Request.Url` to make your code more universal.

Comment: what was issue with static method how ever this works fine with Page Load side.

Comment: @ShalinGajjar Static methods do not have access to instance variables. See [Static vs Non-Static methods](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d218cc1c-a517-4f4f-9bc2-9c1b11c3bf7d/static-method-vs-nonstatic-method?forum=csharpgeneral).